# Installer files not working on Windows 8.1

Tags: out-of-memory, windows-8.1, inno-setup

My installer works fine with Windows 7 32Bit but if run on a Windows8 64 Computer I get an out of memory error during the installation process.

The Windows 7 and the Windows 8 output are created fine with Inno Setup 5.5.5

Comment: Could you maybe provide a little bit of sourcecode ? Is there a part in your [Setup] region where it states ArchitecturesAllowed ? Or otherwise, does it work on Windows 7 64bit ?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry forgot to cancel this.
I discovered my brand new Windows 8.1 computer with 32GB of ram was locked to 4GB of useable ram. I was getting out of memory errors. I have reconfigured the computer and now all is well.